# Need help using 'char tkn'

Tags: c++, char

I have to make a program that asks for the number of rows and number of columns and prints a rectangle based on these values.
The only clue I got was:

> Note that `char tkn` can be used to declare a character.

And I received an example of how input and output should look:

```
The number of lines: 3

The number of columns: 4

Which characters do you want to use: #

####
####
####
```

This is what I got so far (I'm just guessing how to do the `char` bit at the moment):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int lines, columns, character;
    char tkn;
    cout<<"The number of lines: ";
    cin>>lines;
    cout<<"The number of columns ";
    cin>>columns;
    cout<<"What character do you want to use? ";
    cin>>tkn;

    cin.ignore();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you start with the parts you know? For example can you do the input part?

Comment: I edited in what I've done so far

Comment: ok, are you able to write a single `#` on the screen? Can you write multiple in a loop?

Comment: I've worked with loops before, I just dont know how to interpratate the rectangular form into it, and yes I'm able to write a single # on the screen

Comment: @yousseftaoudi Have you heard about nesting?

Comment: No, never heard about nesting before

Comment: So you should be able to write the first line (`####`) on the screen, based on the input provided?

Comment: Adding 1 `#` shouldnt be a problem, but im not sure how to make 4 of them in the same line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int lines, columns, character, i=0, l=0;
        char tkn;
        cout<<"The number of lines: ";
        cin>>lines;
        cout<<"The number of columns ";
        cin>>columns;
        cout<<"What character do you want to use? ";
        cin>>tkn;

        for(l=0;l<lines;l++;) 
        {
        {
         cout<<tkn;
        }
        for(i=0;i<columns;i++) 
        {
        cout<<tkn;
        }
        cout<<endl;
        }
        cin.ignore();
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add header

```
#include <iomanip>
```

and include the following loop

```
std::cout << std::setfill( tkn );
while ( lines-- )
{
    std::cout << std::setw( columns + 1 ) << '\n';
}
```

Also it would be better to use identifier `character` (or simply `c`) or `filler` instead of this strange identifier `tkn`